# Is there a word or frequently-used analogy for something that everyone does but nobody talks about?

Tags: synonyms, analogy

There's a common saying that goes like this:

> XYZ is like sex in high school, everyone's talking about it but nobody does it.

Is there a frequently-used analogy or word for the opposite of that? Something everyone's doing but nobody talks about it.

Comment: There is [**open secret**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/open_secret) but it's about what people know, not what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can suggest is "Elephant in the room"

> = If you say there is an elephant in the room, you mean that there is an obvious problem or difficult situation that people do not want to talk about.
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/an-elephant-in-the-room)

Cambridge suggests it as a difficulty, but it is also more generally used to refer to something obvious that is not talked about:

> An important and obvious topic, which everyone present is aware of, but which isn't discussed, as such discussion is considered to be uncomfortable.
>
> [Phrases org](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/elephant-in-the-room.html)

According to google ngram this is an idiom whose usage has risen to prominence since about the year 2000. The increase and the usage frequency are similar both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: Thank you. It might not work for what I had in mind but it's good to know.

Comment: Thanks. It is a difficult question to which there  may be no perfect answer. I thought of *omerta* but that relates to a state of knowing and remaining silent about criminal activity, which is too far from your specification.